# Is it possible to have multiple queries match multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to get all results which match the query "table" in the `Title` field and match the number "1" in the `CategoryId` field of my `Product` class. Can this be done in elasticsearch/nest?

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have now:

```
response = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<ProductModel>(s => s
                 .From(skip)
                 .Size(itemsPerPage)
                 .Index(indexName)
                 .Query(q => q
                       .SimpleQueryString(qs => qs
                           .Fields(fs => fs
                           .Field(f => f.Title, 3.50)
                           )
                           .Query("" + productSearch.Query + "")
                          )
                        )
                  );
```

I want to get only the results which also have the value "1" in the `CategoryId` field.

Comment: You want a bool query: NEST: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html ES DSL: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminTrent! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Benjamin Trent

In case someone else should have a similar issue, I ended up using the following:

```
response = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<ProductModel>(s => s
                 .From(skip)
                 .Size(itemsPerPage)
                 .Index(indexName)
                 .Query(q => q
                   .Bool(b => b
                       .Should(
                           bs => bs.Term(p => p.CategoryId, productSearch.CategoryId),
                           bs => bs.SimpleQueryString(qs => qs
                                       .Fields(fs => fs
                                       .Field(f => f.Title, 3.50)
                                       .Field(f => f.BrandName, 3.00)
                                       .Field(f => f.Description, 2.00)
                                       )
                                       .Query("" + productSearch.Query + "")
                                       )
                               )
                           )
                       )
                   );
```